# Add extra namespace in node MSXML

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio, msdn, msxml

I want to create a node as follows using MSXML DOM ( MsXml6.h )

```
<name xmlns:a="http://example.com/a" xmlns:b="http://example.com/b" xmlns:c="http://example.com/c>
    <child>child content</child>
    ....
</name>
```

MsXML DOM allows to add one namespace of the prefix using `createNode()` but how to add extra namespaces? `setProperty()` seems to be little different.

Should I use `createAttribute()` as a hack? Is it okay? Or any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no one ever answered this. So I'm giving my own solution here. May be helps someone some time.

Instead of adding an exact namespace, we can add an attribute like:

```
xmlns:ns="http://example.com/path/to/whatever"
```

Where attribute name is `xmlns:ns` and value being `http://example.com/path/to/whatever`

And add this! Done.